# Like button comment box not showing up

Tags: facebook, safari, facebook-like

I have the xfbml version of the like box on one of my sites. All the settings should be correct. The problem is that according to a customer, the comment box does not show up after clicking "like" on Safari (Mac). To be more precise, the actual claim is that after clicking like, she cannot click on the first 3 images in a gallery. An example of a gallery can be found here: REDACTED

What I gather is that the comment box is created, but does not become visible. I have tested this with every browser available to me and cannot replicate the issue.

Has anyone heard of a similar issue or has an idea about what could cause such behavior? A bonus would be if someone with the latest build of Safari on Mac could try and replicate the issue.

edit: To any who might happen upon this question and have the same problem, the solution was to update the Facebook SDK loading script, as pointed out by others below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the click bug. After I click on Like, it likes the page and I'm unable to click on the first 3 images as the Like action adds an iFrame directly under the Like button which is not visible (Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OS 10.7). This iFrame usually shows the option to share the URL with your friends afaik. Hop that helps a bit.

[image]

**Edit_:** The `<head>`tag is empty, the `<body>` tag has the following content:

```
<script>
    var onPageLoad = function() {
        document.domain = 'facebook.com';
        var loc = window.location.toString();
        var index = loc.indexOf('?');
        var qs = loc.substring(index + 1);
        var params = qs.split('&');
        var master_frame_name = '';
        for(var i in params) {
            var components = params[i].split('=');
            if(components[0] == 'master_frame_name') {
                master_frame_name = components[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            var master_frame = parent.frames[master_frame_name];
            master_frame.ExternalNodeConnectWidget.onCommentWidgetLoaded(document);
        } catch (e) {
        }
    };

</script>
```

**Edit2_:** Yes, a lot of errors ;-)

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://i-marbella.com/Gallery/gallery/elle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1 from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2Fi-marbellacom%2F232037653472920&width=200&colorscheme=dark&connections=16&stream=false&header=true&height=500. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://i-marbella.com/Gallery/gallery/elle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1 from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://i-marbella.com/Gallery/gallery/elle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1 from frame with URL https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&size=medium&count=true&annotation=&hl=en-US&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fwidget%2F__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fver%3DDIroZ-_zuh0.de.%2Fsv%3D1%2Fam%3D!4EfSXeE4ZPeIc6DnWw%2Fd%3D1%2F#id=I1_1324022904362&parent=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com&rpctoken=361259257&_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://i-marbella.com/Gallery/gallery/elle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1 from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
/files/Upload/Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
Unable to post message to http://www.stumbleupon.com. Recipient has origin http://i-marbella.com.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90 from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_widget_shell.php?locale=en_US&master_frame_name=f2429d9b8c&sdk=joey. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_widget_shell.php?locale=en_US&master_frame_name=f2429d9b8c&sdk=joey from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.stumbleupon.com/badge/embed/4/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1 from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&size=medium&count=true&annotation=&hl=en-US&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fwidget%2F__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fver%3DDIroZ-_zuh0.de.%2Fsv%3D1%2Fam%3D!4EfSXeE4ZPeIc6DnWw%2Fd%3D1%2F#id=I1_1324022904362&parent=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com&rpctoken=361259257&_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html#_=1324022903982&_version=2&count=none&enableNewSizing=false&id=twitter-widget-0&lang=en&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&size=m&text=Elle%20Morgan%20Fashion%20Show%20in%20Golden%20Goose%20Marbella&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1 from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/hub.html from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df13f32e14%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fi-marbella.com%252Ff24421c7a8%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fi-marbella.com%2FGallery%2Fgallery%2Felle-morgan-fashion-show-in-golden-goose-marbella-1&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Comment: Thank you, that is immensely helpful, as so far I was fairly skeptical about the bug's existence. From that pic I see that the <head> tag is empty. Is this the case for the <body> tag as well?

Comment: Seems like the Javascript is failing to load the contents of the comment box. Does it produce some sort of error?

Answer (score 3):

Today, I also encountered the same problem, you can try to change the import https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js, this is HTTPS.

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

We have had same problem. In our case, Facebook API initialization script was loaded statically, which caused the problem (somebody downloaded the script and included it into web application). After change to standard dynamic initialization in compliance with [facebook manual](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Facebook bug:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293075054049400

Basically, one gets this behavior if secure browsing is enabled on the Facebook user's account.